# PFQueryCollectionViewController not showing new data when added

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I've been exploring how to create a social application that allows users to share photos. I used Parse as a backend and one of the functions of the app is to allow users to save pictures to Parse, and view all the photos currently saved to Parse.

My app currently pushes the photo to the Parse server just fine. However, I'm greeted with odd behaviour when I attempt to display the uploaded photos on my "Wall".

Here's how I'm saving the photo to Parse:

```
let pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "someImage"))
let file = PFFile(name: "image", data: pictureData)
file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ succeeded, error in
    if succeeded {
        let wallObject = WallObject(imageFile: file)
        wallObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { succeeded, error in
            if succeeded { println("Succeeded saving picture to Parse") }
            if let error = error { println("Error saving object: \(error)") }
        }
    } else {
        println("Error saving file to Parse: \(error)")
    }
})
```

Saving works fine, and when I check the Parse database on the website, the image is there. However, when I try to display the images in my `PFQueryCollectionViewController` subclass (by using the pullDownToRefresh), the new image will not insert itself as a new cell, but instead replace one of the old images, kicking the oldest image from the collectionView while preserving the same number of cells even after a new object has been fetched from Parse.

Aside from subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout` and doing some layout code, I the `PFQueryCollectionViewController` is set up very minimally. With `println(objects.count)` statements in `objectsWillLoad` and `objectsDidLoad` methods, I assured myself that the new object has been loaded to the `objects` data array.

**Attempts at a solution:**
I tried `collectionView!.reloadData`, setting up a button that calls `reloadObjects`, using collectionView's `performBatchUpdates` and was greeted with this error: `UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:`

**Bottom line:** Although the `PFQueryCollectionViewController` recognized the new object upon refreshing at runtime, it will not insert a new cell to accommodate for the new item.

The one caveat to this is when the Parse database is completely empty and a new picture is uploaded to Parse, the collectionView can correctly generate 1 new Cell for the new image.

---

**PFQueryCollectionViewController dataSource implementation**

```
  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFCollectionViewCell? {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FeedViewCollectionCell
    if cell == nil {
      cell = FeedViewCollectionCell()
    }
    cell!.populateDataWithObject(object as! CollectionCellData)
    return cell
  }
```

Comment: PFQueryCollectionViewController did you check its datasource protocol methods? It should be similar to tableview or collectionview

Comment: Yeah, I am under the impression nothing is wrong with my implementation. Perhaps not. I'll post that too to make sure.

Comment: "Aside from subclassing UICollectionViewLayout and doing some layout code" this is suspect, did you try without your custom layout?

Comment: Looking into that now @ChrisWagner

Comment: @ChrisWagner Love you, I overlooked the fact I was cacheing the layout attributes and did not factor in new attributes in the event of insertion/deletion. Please post an answer so I can award the bounty!

Comment: well that was unexpectedly easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aside from subclassing UICollectionViewLayout and doing some layout
>   code

This is suspect, did you try without your custom layout?

Answer (score 0):

in cellForItemAtIndexPath put this:

```
    cell?.imageView.image = nil its work for me
```